# Websphere FTE agent going to Unreachable state

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte, websphere-mq-ams

Facing issues with IBM websphere FTE agent.This agent is deployed in UNIX system.The usual load on this agent used to be around 300 files per day.Now the load has increased significantly from 300 to 2500/day.Because of this the agent is going down again and again.
   Tried fixing the issue by creating multiple monitors polling the same source folder.But the problem still persists,since multiple monitors polls for the same files and throws file doesnot exist exception.

Please help what are the ways i can fix this issue.

Comment: What version are you on? does agent log files have anything?

Comment: Anything in the agent logs?

Comment: Logs says "co ordination queue manager could not be contacted or refused a connection".Sorry for the delay as we had to transfer files manually. I got involved with  it.

Comment: Hi Shashi..do u have any solution in your mind..

Comment: The message is error log will have a MQ Reason code as to why the agent failed connect to co-ordination queue manager to publish status message. That could give an idea as to what's going wrong. Suggest you to look at this link also:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/trouble_agent_unreachable.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

I believe your agent is running out of memory, consider increasing memory or control number of simultaneous transfer.